# How to restrict my PC to browsing only for security reasons?

Tags: protocols

I have a PC that i only use for browsing the web. I do not have any problem with disabling any other services/protocols that does not affect web browsing.
I want to disable these unnecessary services (For example: Server Message Block).
So i need a complete accurate list of these services ( not just internet services may other things ex: usb ports)

Comment: Install Chrome OS?

Comment: Windows services and hardware components are often tied together in ways that are not immediately apparent, but can cause issues further down the line. Think carefully about what types of attacks you are trying to prevent and take steps to mitigate those. Do not follow a 'lockdown for the sake of lockdown' model as you can do more harm than good. For example, disabling USB ports, is this PC ever in a public, unattended setting where an open USB port could be exploited? For SMB, do you need to disable the service (which is tightly integrated with win management) or is a firewall block enough?

Answer (score 1):

What O/S? You can go into your services menu, click any service, and right click any service and go into Dependency tab. This will indicate any dependent services. You should Google a service if you do not know what it is , or what it does.